# How to add custom master page options to the Kentico new website wizard

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, kentico

I'm in the process of building a new website and I am making use of the Kentico **new website wizard**.

On step 5, you get to select a master page. Currently I see 2 default options.

How am I able to add my own custom master page that I created and saved in the CMSTemplates folder?

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you created the template in CMSTemplates - I assume it is ASPX template, have you registered it in Kentico as master page template? If not, please see the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-websites-using-aspx-templates/creating-master-pages-for-aspx-templates) on creating ASPX templates.

Comment: Thanks man. Worked! I must just learn to read the damn documentation!

Answer (score 0):

It really does not matter. You can go with default blank master page or any other option and later on you can change it. After creating a site you will end with one root element in the tree and the master template assigned to it (the one you chose in the wizard). Now you can change your master template: go to `page templates` and create a new one, then go back to the root page and go to root page properties/template and assign the one you created. 
This root master template is not some "read only? frozen forever" thing. You can change it to different one at any point at time.

P.S. If you want your template appear in the site wizard - just create it in advance, mark it as master template and it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** things required to do.
Put the newly created template in the **"Templates"** folder then run an insert statement in SQL to **"register"** the template so that it will show up when in Kentico when you want to create a new site from the internal web templates.

This is how I did it.

In order for the user to click to add a new website so that our new custom website template is displayed in the list of websites,we need to add this information to the **CMS_WebTemplate** database table so that Kentico can map or **“register”** the physical path to the custom website template.

The script is as follows:
INSERT INTO CMS_WebTemplate 
SELECT        'New Site For Testing',
              '~\App_Data\Templates\BlankNewSite',
              '{$webtemplate.blanksite.description$}',
              NEWID(),
              GETDATE(),
              'BlankNewSite',
              10,**--order of the website template so you need to look for the last digit and increment by 1**
              'F;B;N;X;V',
              'a928c1d2-1bcd-459c-abcb-9f5a08978017', **--default web thumbnail id for the blank site**
              The Blank New Site for testing provides a template for creating new websites from scratch, based on the portal engine.'

Now, the user will be able to create a new website using the new template that was placed in the **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico10\CMS\App_Data\Templates** directory which lives inside of the Kentico CMS web application

**Steps:**
**1.**  Clone and rename existing website templates from **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico10\CMS\App_Data\Templates**
**2.**  Run script in the database to map the website template and it’s physical path
**3.**  Run wizard to create new website